# How could I rewrite this to remove the gotos without loss of speed or readability?

Tags: string, vb6, split, goto

I wrote this. Yes, I know it's VB6. Yes, it is production code, and, yeah, I know it uses gotos. I am a lazy, evil beast ...

So show me (and the rest of us) how it *should* be written

```
Public Function SplitString(ByVal sText As Variant) As Variant
    Dim nHere As Long
    Dim cHere As String * 1
    Dim aRes As Variant
    Dim nRes As Long
    Dim bInquote As Boolean
    Dim sString As String
    ReDim aRes(0)
    nHere = 1
    nRes = 0
    Do
    If nHere > Len(sText) Then Exit Do
    cHere = Mid$(sText, nHere, 1)
    If cHere = Chr$(32) Then
        If bInquote Then
        sString = sString & cHere
        GoTo nextChar
        End If
        If sString <> vbNullString Then
        aRes(nRes) = sString
        sString = vbNullString
        nRes = nRes + 1
        ReDim Preserve aRes(nRes)
        End If
        GoTo nextChar
    ElseIf cHere = Chr$(34) Then
        bInquote = Not bInquote
        GoTo nextChar
    Else
        sString = sString & cHere
    End If
nextChar:
    nHere = nHere + 1
    Loop
    If sString <> vbNullString Then
    aRes(nRes) = sString
    End If
    SplitString = aRes
End Function
```

By the way, it splits a string into an array. The elements in the string may be quoted.

Comment: Why do you think it is fast and readable at the moment?

Comment: Are you telling me it's neither?

Comment: The DO loop should be a counting (FOR?) loop.  That would eliminate the need for the nextChar label.  You might optimize things a bit by not recomputing LEN(sText) on each iteration (it doesn't change).  Actually, even with the DO loop, you don't need the label if you restructure the space handling to use ELSEIF instead of consecutive IF statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this particular bit of logic should be clearly and easily implemented using Split() and Join() operations.  While one can always write a long run of inline code that improves on them in speed there are two reasons not to:

- The performance difference probably will not even approach a factor of 1.5 and such logic is seldom used millions of times on extremely large strings.
- Such inline logic is not only opaque and difficult to maintain, it is hard to get right the first time when writing the program.

Example:

```
Function SplitString(ByVal Text As String) As String()
    Dim Slices() As String
    Dim UnquotedSlice As Long

    Slices = Split(Text, """")
    For UnquotedSlice = 0 To UBound(Slices) Step 2
        Slices(UnquotedSlice) = Replace$(Slices(UnquotedSlice), " ", vbNullChar)
    Next
    SplitString = Split(Join$(Slices, ""), vbNullChar)
End Function
```

BTW: Kudos to anyone who can fix the perverse code-quoting markup this site uses in my example above.

Edit: Nevermind, I winkled it out.  The bulletted list gave the parser a spasm.

Comment: Wow, that's impressive stuff! I would never have thought of that approach in million years.

Comment: It isn't perfect.  The occurrence of multiple space runs outside the quotes will result in a few empty elements in the resulting array.  You could try collapsing those spaces in each unquoted "slice" though.

Comment: Ah, yes, just discovered that and was about to point it out, but you've beaten me to the punch.

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty simple:

Change "If sString <> vbNullString Then" to "ElseIf sString <> vbNullString Then", remove all "Goto"s and remove "nextChar:".

```
Public Function SplitString(ByVal sText As Variant) As Variant
    Dim nHere As Long
    Dim cHere As String * 1
    Dim aRes As Variant
    Dim nRes As Long
    Dim bInquote As Boolean
    Dim sString As String
    ReDim aRes(0)
    nHere = 1
    nRes = 0
    Do
        If nHere > Len(sText) Then Exit Do
        cHere = Mid$(sText, nHere, 1)
        If cHere = Chr$(32) Then
            If bInquote Then
                sString = sString & cHere
            ElseIf sString <> vbNullString Then
                aRes(nRes) = sString
                sString = vbNullString
                nRes = nRes + 1
                ReDim Preserve aRes(nRes)
            End If
        ElseIf cHere = Chr$(34) Then
            bInquote = Not bInquote
        Else
            sString = sString & cHere
        End If

        nHere = nHere + 1
    Loop
    If sString <> vbNullString Then
        aRes(nRes) = sString
    End If
    SplitString = aRes
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look here, for an idea of how subtle optimizations affect this sort of task:

http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/c_Split.htm

You'll see that amongst those algorithms, there is no **best** one, but rather some pretty good ones and then some that can really whoop the outlyers a bit better than others.

Answer (score 1):

I heard a rule of thumb that says that if your goto jumps forward, it's probably okay.  This looks like one of those cases.  If you can reverse the logic of a predicate, though, seems easier.

Comment: Interesting take on the issue. 

At the assembler level, of course, everything pretty much resolves to gotos (a.k.a. jumps)

Comment: There's another rule of thumb: don't GOTO where you would end up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty straight forward.  Just make use of the if/else structure.  If your code enters an if block, it will never enter corresponding elseif or else blocks.  A lot of your goto statements aren't even needed in the first place.

```
Public Function SplitString(ByVal sText As Variant) As Variant
    Dim nHere As Long
    Dim cHere As String * 1
    Dim aRes As Variant
    Dim nRes As Long
    Dim bInquote As Boolean
    Dim sString As String
    ReDim aRes(0)
    nHere = 1
    nRes = 0
    Do
        If nHere > Len(sText) Then Exit Do
        cHere = Mid$(sText, nHere, 1)
        If cHere = Chr$(32) Then
            If bInquote Then
                sString = sString & cHere
            ElseIf sString <> vbNullString Then
                aRes(nRes) = sString
                sString = vbNullString
                nRes = nRes + 1
                ReDim Preserve aRes(nRes)
            End If
        ElseIf cHere = Chr$(34) Then
            bInquote = Not bInquote
        Else
            sString = sString & cHere
        End If
        nHere = nHere + 1
    Loop
    If sString <> vbNullString Then
        aRes(nRes) = sString
    End If
    SplitString = aRes
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd simply use the [Split function](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb-string-array-functions-split-join-filter) and [Join functions](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb-string-array-functions-split-join-filter) that is native to VB6. I'll leave the details to you but the basic flow is to split on the spaces and then rejoin objects that are *between* the quotes.

I've not written VB6 in years and I don't have the software installed (for debugging) so I don't want to take a stab at the function.

Best Luck,
Frank

Comment: But if you'd read the code, I was also wanting to be able to split strings like
  my dog "has fleas"
into an array
  "my", "dog", "has fleas"

Comment: And if you read my link, you'd see the JOIN function would would still allow you to implement your concept. In addition, the code isn't "readable".

Comment: Please could you unpack just how Split and Join do the job? It's late at night here in Australia, and I'm not thinking too well.